# Evaluate perl output in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I would like to evaluate the output of a Perl script run in a bash for loop.

My Perl script `get_contigs.pl` outputs a single number, and I would like to delete or keep a file depending on this number. I'm trying to do this inside of an if statement as follows:

```
if [ $(perl get_contigs.pl file.txt) < 130 ]
  then
  rm file.txt
  fi
```

But it exits with the error `-bash: 130: No such file or directory`

When I run this script outside of the loop: `perl get_contigs.pl file.txt`

I get the expected output. (In this particular case the output is `110` - so I want to remove this file).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To compare numbers within `[  ]`, use `-eq`, `-lt`, etc. `<` in Bash has another meaning (to read from a file, for example).

Comment: @fedorqui "Face, meet palm"